# Preforming math stored in variables

Tags: php

I have 3 variables like this:
$first = 2;
$second = 5;
$operation = '*';

how can I programaticly assign the solution to this math problem to the $answer variable?
I have tried eval(), but that does not work.

Comment: Good idea to mention that you tried eval(). However, it would be good to also post the actual code you tried, so people wouldn't have to guess what you did.

Comment: @Greg good point, but I have accepted an answer already so it's a little late now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

eval() should work perfectly fine for something like this. Remember that eval() returns NULL though, unless you tell it to return something.

```
<?php
$first = 3;
$second = 4;
$operation = "*";

$answer = eval('return '.$first.$operation.$second.';');

echo $answer;
?>
```

Comment: Remember to clean and verify the input! If any of the three variables are set by a user they can potentially be used for injection attacks!

Comment: All the input is coming from me it is being built randomly.

Answer (score 6):

```
function add($a, $b) {
    return $a + $b;
}

function multiply($a, $b) {
    return $a * $b;
}

function divide($a, $b) {
    return $a / $b;
}

$operations = array(
    '+' => 'add',
    '*' => 'multiply',
    '/' => 'divide',
);

$a = 2;
$b = 5;
$operation = '*';

echo $operations[$operation]($a, $b);
```

Comment: That's ok. It's indeed simpler, but don't forget to filter input if you're going to eval it.

Comment: All the input is coming from me it is being built randomly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning on doing this calculation often, I would strongly recommend against using the eval method and instead use the method Ionut G. Stan posted above. I know it's more complicated, but each time you run eval, PHP loads the compiler engine all over again, and so it has a high overhead cost. You'll get a major performance increase (around 10x) if you use the function dispatch approach Ionut showed. Take a look at the comments on the eval function in the PHP manual and you'll see other people who have also been saying this: http://www.php.net/eval

I was once using eval hoping it would enable me to construct a fast templating mechanism for a web application, but calls to eval were very slow, and when I realised that eval was causing it I switched to a different approach. The speed gains were phenomenal.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me:

```
var_dump(eval("return $first $operator $second;"));
```

But `eval` is evil. You should better use a function like this:

```
function foobar($operator)
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    array_shift($args);
    switch ($operator) {
    case "*":
        if (count($args) < 1) {
            return false;
        }
        $result = array_shift($args) * array_shift($args);
        break;
    /*
        …
    */
    }
    if (count($args)) {
        return call_user_func_array(__FUNCTION__, array_merge(array($operator, $result), $args));
    }
    return $result;
}
var_dump(foobar("*", 3, 5, 7));
```